# How to get id of div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{"__reactInternalInstance$scd8ef5s9":{"tag":5,"key":null,"elementType":"div","type":"div","stateNode":"~","return":{"tag":5,"key":null,"elementType":"div","type":"div","stateNode":{"__reactInternalInstance$scd8ef5s9":"~__reactInternalInstance$scd8ef5s9~return","__reactEventHandlers$scd8ef5s9":{"id":0,"style":{"position":"absolute","zIndex":0,"display":"flex","justifyContent":"center","alignItems":"center","width":100,"height":100,"backgroundColor":"white"},"className":"box resizable","children":[{"type":"div","key":null,"ref":null,"props": "props..." ......

console.log(CircularJSON.stringify($(this).find("div")[0]));
```

Prints it.

Here is the html:

```
  <div
    className="myClass"
  >
    <div
      className="resizerClass"
      id="tomatoes"
       >
        <div className="resizers">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="resizers"></div>
  </div>
```

I need the id os resizerClass div? how to get it?

Comment: FYI, circular-json is deprecated.

Comment: Why are you trying to turn DOM elements into JSON in the first place? They contain references to the state of the DOM, they can't be restored later when you parse the JSON.

Comment: Dont need to restore them later. I just need to get the Id inside the div children of the $(this).find("div")[0]) object.

Comment: So why do you need to use JSON? Just access the properties of the DOM element.

Comment: `$(this).find("div").eq(0).children()`

Comment: how to get div id from children?

Comment: Add `.attr('id')`. This is all just basic jQuery stuff.

Comment: this leads me to undefined

Comment: Are you sure the children have IDs? Show the HTML that you're trying to process.

Comment: `<div className="resizerClass" id={id}>` is not valid HTML

Comment: Are you working with React? https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html#introducing-internal-instances

Comment: I want to do the jquery way.

Comment: $(this).children().attr("id") it is

Comment: `@Jacs` You can find `ID` of `className=resizerClass` attribute from more methods like **$(this).find('div').eq(0).children().attr('id');** `or` **$('body>div>div').attr('id');** `or` **$('[className="resizerClass"]').attr('id');** `or` **$('body>div div:nth-child(1)').attr('id');** `or` **$('body>div div:first-child').attr('id');**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find `ID` by *jQuery* as your HTML attributes(`className`) then you can define attribute in square bracket like `$('[className="resizerClass"]')` and get other attributes value like `attr('id')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var getId = $('[className="resizerClass"]').attr('id');
  console.log('id='+getId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div className="myClass">
  <div className="resizerClass" id="tomatoes">
    <div className="resizers"></div>
  </div>
  <div className="resizers"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me: `var getId = $('.resizerClass').attr('id');`